# There are no active runners online GitLab

Tags: xcode, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a problem with GitLab it won't run my UI tests from an Xcode project.

I get an error: This job is stuck because of one of the following problems. There are no active runners online, no runners for the protected branch, or no runners that match all of the job's tags: saas-macos-medium-m1

My yml file is:

```
stages:
  - test

ui_tests:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - saas-macos-medium-m1
  script:
    - xcodebuild test -workspace DatePlanner.xcodeproj -scheme DatePlanner -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad (9th generation)' -configuration Debug
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - DerivedData/
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

Becouse its xcode i am trying to run it on tags with the mac machines which are available from gitlab runners.

[image]

I expect that the xcui tests are runned.

Comment: What Gitlab plan are you on. macos runners are not available on the free plan, only to premium and ultimate subscriptions https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/hosted_runners/macos.html